# Инверсия вывода данных из базы данных на Ruby

Tags: массивы, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Как реализовать инверсию вывода комментов из бд?другими словами,последние добавленные комменты(и другие данные)выводились не в конце странички,а помещались вверх списка? код:

```
<% posts.each do |post| %>
<h3><% post.comment %></h3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно при выводе из базы данных, данные сортируются по одному или нескольким столбцам. Если таблица комментариев снабжена календарным столбцом `created_at`, можно отсортировать по нему в обратном порядке. Для этого его нужно снабдить ключевым словом `desc` (чтобы в SQL запросе сформировалась обратная сортировка `SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY created_at DESC`)

```
posts = Post.order('created_at desc')
```

В последних версиях RoR поддерживается символьный формат

```
posts = Post.order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Небольшая ремарка. С точки зрения архитектуры, лучше убрать это в скоуп.

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно сортировать по такому принципу часто, то можно установить сортировку в scope

```
scope :order_desc, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
```

После того как Вы определили scope в модели, можно определить в переменную все посты в нужном порядке:

```
posts = Post.order_desc
```

Comment: Манипуляций с дефолтным скоупом лучше не делать. Это может иметь труднопредсказуемые последствия.

Comment: ...а если уж советовать его менять, то объяснять, почему это крайняя мера и когда она может быть полезна. И как её при случае обойти.

Comment: Другое дело. И вишенку б на торт: пример использования.

Comment: Уже лучше! Осталось поправить синтаксическую ошибку. Если, конечно, ничего нового не возникнет ._.

Comment: Спасибо, за замечания.